# Angular http client return false when 204 http code

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I made a http post request with my angular service and i'm waiting for a boolean return.
But with the 204 http code response with no content, angular return false.

This is my service function :

```
public create(
        base_price: number,
        domain_id: number|null
    ): Observable<boolean> {
        this.isLoadingSubject.next(true);
        return this.http.post<boolean>(`${API_URL}/pictures`, {
            base_price,
            domain_id
        })
        .pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoadingSubject.next(false)))
    }
```

And my component :

```
submit() {
        this.hasError = false;
        const create = this.pictureService
            .create(
                this.f.base_price.value,
                this.f.domain_id.value,
            )
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe((result: boolean) => {
                this.hasError = !result;
            });
        this.unsubscribe.push(create);
    }
```

So the create function return false and i didn't find a solution to catch the 204 status in my case.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to check whether the response is 204?

If that's the case you can just simply just have to add the `observe: response` to the options.

```
this.http.post < boolean > (`${API_URL}/pictures`, {
  base_price,
  domain_id
}, {
  observe: 'response'
})
```

Then you check the response status like

```
submit() {
        this.hasError = false;
        const create = this.pictureService
            .create(
                this.f.base_price.value,
                this.f.domain_id.value,
            )
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(response => {
                if (response.status !== 204) {
                   // Do whatever
                }
            });
        this.unsubscribe.push(create);
    }
```

HttpClient docs https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 0):

What if we were to read the error status and if it is 204 we return false? In my case I am getting a 404 but you could swap it for 204.

```html
<div class="card text-center m-3">
    <h5 class="card-header">POST request with error handling</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        Error message: {{errorMessage}}
        <br>
        I will return boolean: {{returnBool}}
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'post-request-error-handling',
  templateUrl: 'post-request-error-handling.component.html',
})
export class PostRequestErrorHandlingComponent implements OnInit {
  postId;
  errorMessage;
  returnBool: boolean;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .post<any>('https://reqres.in/invalid-url', {
        title: 'Angular POST Request Example',
      })
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          this.postId = data.id;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          this.errorMessage = error.message;
          console.error('There was an error!', error);
          if (error.status == 404) {
            console.log('Return boolean false');
            this.returnBool = false;
          }
        },
      });
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-post-examples-hpa8pv?file=app%2Fcomponents%2Fpost-request-error-handling.component.ts